# PHPUnit Error: Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::visit()

Tags: laravel, phpunit

This is the test case I've written and when i try to run it with this command `vendor/bin/phpunit` on linux it gives me the error "Call to undefined method Tests\Unit\ExampleTest::visit()"

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicTest()
    {
        $this->visit('/Login')
             ->type('KP123@gmail.com','email')
             ->type('123456','password')
             ->press('Login')
             ->seePageIs('/home')
             ->see('Katy Perry');
    }
}
```

I've tried running composer update and it still could not work. Had Anyone experienced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

The `visit()` method looks like it's part of the SeleniumTestCase. So my guess is you either extend from the wrong base class. I assume it should look something like this:

```
class ExampleTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    // your test method
}
```

edit: I just noticed the Laravel tag, so it's probably more something like `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase`. If this gives you errors that it can't find the class you have to set the bootstrap file in your `phpunit.xml` to the `vendor/autoload.php` or another appropriate bootstrap file where the file is registered in the autoloader.

Comment: I've already had the TestCase tag also tried extending PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase and it gives me a Fatal error instead

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct namespace for your TestCase class you extend from? Maybe use your IDE if the method signature exists. Especially with Laravel some test functionality is moved to Traits so you might have to use one of them as well.

Comment: I think that there might be some package im missing but I'm not sure which one to download

Comment: OK, I just found this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#introduction Are you using that ExampleTest? In that case I assume the code should be fine and we should look at other problems. Did you do a composer install in your base directory to make sure you have all the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I might have come in late onto this question but here is my 2 cents. I have been trying to use the same methods with my test case which led to a dismal failure.

I the realised that I could actually make use of the TestResponse class which is found on the Foundation namespace that wraps many methods around the response object.

```
$this->get('/url/to/visit'); //Then you can make your assertions on the returned response.
```

In my case I had authentication turned on for the application therefore it always complained about the header view where we display the username of the currently logged in user. If you run into that situation then use the Auth Facade like shown below:

```
\Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

You should now be able to assert that your response has some text in it. Hope this helps. By the way I am on Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0):

If you are using new version of Laravel you must use [Laravel Dusk](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/dusk) to use similar methods to `$this->visit` or `see`. It was excluded from Laravel around version 6.

Instead you can use, but it has limited options:

```
$this->get('/Login')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require laravel/browser-kit-testing --dev
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

if you are using > Laravel 8 try :

`$this->get('/Login')`

instead of visit function, and `assertSeeText` instead of `see`